# Making multiple tooltip follow on mousemove

Tags: javascript

I have multiple spans within the same class whom I want to follow the cursor using a mousemove property.

I have tried with document.querySelectorAll, document.querySelector, document.getElementById, document.getElementsByClassName, addEventListener...

This is the actual working code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97o6vdxj/1/)

```js
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip1');
  var x = e.clientX,
      y = e.clientY;

  tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
}
```

```css
.para {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
.para span {
  display: none;
}
.para:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ttip {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px 0px 0 #000, 0px 1px 0 #000, -1px 0px 0 #000, 0px -1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">
  Some text <span id="tooltip1" class="ttip">and here is a follower tooltip</span>
</p>
<p class="para">
  Some other text <span id="tooltip2" class="ttip">I want this to follow too, but without defining again for each new span tag</span>
</p>
```

The farther I've got is the first span element following mouse, but not the others.
I wish the other tag's tooltip to follow cursor as well, but without defining again for each new span tag I put in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no issues doing this with `querySelectorAll` on the class and then looping over the resulting elements with a `.forEach()`

```js
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
      y = e.clientY;

  var tooltipSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.ttip');

  tooltipSpans.forEach(tooltipSpan => {
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
  });
}
```

```css
.para {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.para span {
  display: none;
}

.para:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ttip {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px 0px 0 #000, 0px 1px 0 #000, -1px 0px 0 #000, 0px -1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">
  Some text <span id="tooltip1" class="ttip">and here is a follower tooltip</span>
</p>
<p class="para">
  Some other text <span id="tooltip2" class="ttip">I want this to follow too, but without defining again for each new span tag</span>
</p>
```

**EDIT**

Some clarification, here is kind of a breakdown for whats happening.

```
var tooltipSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.ttip');
```

this returns an array of DOM nodes with the class name `ttip`

```
tooltipSpans.forEach(func)
```

This performs a function on each element within an array

```
tooltipSpan => {
  tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
}
```

This is an arrow function.  It is almost the same as:

```
function alignSpan(tooltipSpan) {
  tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
}
```

except for slightly different scoping, see [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more info.  It is a nice way of shortening the syntax for functions, especially when you're declaring them inline (like inside a forEach).

Here is another way you could write this which might look more familiar.

```
function alignSpan(tooltipSpan) {
  tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
}

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
      y = e.clientY;

  var tooltipSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.ttip');

  tooltipSpans.forEach(alignSpan);
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie in frontend. This exact part `(tooltipSpan => {` I missed in all the code templates I've searched for. I just didn't knew what I had to do. This is exactly what I need. Thanks! _I can accept an answer only 10 minutes after it was posted. I will accept it later._

Comment: No problem!  By the way, this is just a shortened way of performing this function using some newer Javascript techniques known as arrow functions.  I will post an edit describing what it's doing!

Comment: I'm looking forward to it :)

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event's `target` and search under it for a tooltip.

```js
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var tooltipSpan = e.target.querySelector('.ttip')

  if (tooltipSpan) {
    var x = e.clientX,
      y = e.clientY;

    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
.para {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.para .ttip {
  display: none;
}

.para:hover .ttip {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ttip {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px 0px 0 #000, 0px 1px 0 #000, -1px 0px 0 #000, 0px -1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">
  Some text <span id="tooltip1" class="ttip">and here is a follower tooltip</span>
</p>
<p class="para">
  Some other text <span id="tooltip2" class="ttip">I want this to follow too, but without defining again for each new span tag</span>
</p>
```

Comment: This one runs only on the hovered item, so it doesn't do for every class item?

Comment: it does by showing only the tooltip inside the hovered element. So it works for all without loops.

Comment: Cool, +1 for that :)

Comment: I was trying this one, but the browser console shows error everytime I move the mouse inside the page it throws an error `TypeError: tooltipSpan is null`. Is this expected, avoid-able, or is indeed an error? I am guessing this does not affect UX at all, but I don't know.

Comment: @Kelvin updated code to make it a bit more defensive for such cases.